# Why this javascript does not work?

Tags: javascript

I am having some trouble with this code, I tested it online but it doesn't seem to work. This is all of my coding:

My HTML:

```
<img src="kruisje.jpg" id="image1">
```

And the script that SHOULD make it a slideshow but doesn't:

```
var img = document.getElementById("image1").src;
        function changeimage(){
            wait(10)
            for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
                return img
            }   
        }   
        var images = ["","","","","",""]
```

And I know the links in the array aren't filled in but I have the links for it ready. They are just pictures so you can fill in any url you want if you are testing it.

Can somebody say me what i am doing wrong on this code?

Comment: there is no `wait` function in JavaScript.

Comment: `changeimage` is never ever executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Depending on *when* you run it, `document.getElementById("image1")` may return an element or `null`. If it returns `null` the script will error when you try to access the `src` property and abort.
2. You never call the `changeimage` function
3. There is no `wait` function in JavaScript and you don't appear to have defined one.
4. You `return img`, so you exit the function on the first time you go around the loop
5. If you wanted to assign a new URL to `img` then you would just be assigning the URL to the variable.  `img` will be a variable containing a string. It won't reference the `src` property.

If you want to do this, you need to completely change your approach.

```
// Get a reference to the element (make sure you run this *after* the image has been added to the DOM)
var img = document.getElementById("image1");

// Track where you are in the array
var imagesIndex = 0;
var images = ["","","","","",""]

function changeImage(){
    // Assign the new URL to the src property of the image
    img.src = images[imagesIndex];
    // Increment the index here
    imageIndex++;
    // Check if it has gone off the end and reset it if it has
    if (imageIndex >= images.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
}

// Call the function on your time period
setInterval(changeImage, 10000);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var img = document.getElementById("image1").src;
        function changeimage(){
            wait(10) // ERROR FUNCTION
            setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
            for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
                return img
            }   
        }   
        var images = ["","","","","",""]
```

you need use setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);

Comment: setTimeout and not setInterval